# Remove Line Break formula with Custom Label not working 100% of the time

Tags: formula, line-break

I'm trying to remove the break line from Billing street field with a solution that was posted [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/es-MX/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8exxSAB), however, I have found that it is only working on certain records, and for some, the break line is still present.

This is the formula that I'm using.

```
SUBSTITUTE( BillingStreet ,SUBSTITUTE($Label.linebreak, "-", "")," ")
```

[image]

The address above is not getting cleaned and still being printed like this:

[image]

BUT, if I do a backspace at the start of the 8H and then do a break line, it works now???
[image: After doing backspace and break line again]

[image]

I have inspected the hidden characters in the text that I'm trying to clean, and I get the same 2 hidden characters for all scenarios, the ones that work and the ones that don't and even for the ones I edit to make them work.
[image]

Any ideas how to fix?